# Could someone help me with this regex?

Tags: regex, hubspot

I am setting up lead scoring in HubSpot. It uses regex for expressions, but I'm having trouble defining it the way I want to.

**Scenario**

```
abc.com/experience/

abc.com/experience/case-study-name-one

abc.com/experience/case-study-name-two

abc.com/experience/case-study-name-three
```

I want to score the user 2 points for visiting /experience and 5 points for visiting a case study.

This is what I've tried:

```
(.*experience/.*)
```

That aim was to score any URL which has something after the second /
However, what is happening is anyone accessing `/experience` (ie the case study holding page, not an individual case study) is getting a score of 5 (or 7 if they've visited both), but not the correct score which is 2.

Can anyone see the issues in my expression?

Thanks a lot!

Eben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use 2 different regex for the point assignment:

Regex for the 2 points scoring:

```
^(.*experience/?)$
```

This first regex, impose that the URL ends with `experience` or `experience/`.

Regex for the 5 points scoring:

```
^(.*experience/.+)$
```

The following regex, impose that the URL ends with **some characters** after the string `experience/`

Have a look at this link to play with the regex: https://regex101.com/r/ZAcXvZ/1/

Last but not least, it might be interesting to replace the `.` in your regex by something more restrictive to match only your hostname and pages that respect only a specific naming (like `case-study-name.+` for example)

Comment: @Eben.W: great that it helped you! Could you mark the answer as the correct answer? Thanks!